# filtering characters out of a username (py)

Tags: python

i wanted to create a terminal game using python. A username is needed for the database, but i dont want the user’s username to be random special characters. So i decided to filter characters, but didnt work as i planned.

the code i used:

```
# Python3
import string
username = input(“Username = “)
random_var = 0
filter = [string.digits, string.ascii_letters, “_”]
while True:
  try:
    if username[random_var] in filter:
      random_var += 1
    else:
      print(“Error, inappropriate username.”)
      break
  except IndexError:
    print(“Success with 0 errors.”)
```

Answer (score 0):

regex would lead to more readable code here, and you might want to ask for the username repeatedly until a valid one is input

`\w` matches characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _

```py
import re

while True:
    try:
        username = input("Username = ")
        assert re.fullmatch('\w+', username)
        break
    except AssertionError:
        print("Error, inappropriate username.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it, because your code uses fancy quotes (`“”`) instead of normal double quotes (`"`) and I don't think it will run as a valid Python program. Probably you pasted the code into MS Word or something like that which autoformatted them. Don't do that. In any case, I don't want to spend time fixing all the quotes but this line is wrong:

```
filter = [string.digits, string.ascii_letters, “_”]
```

`string.digits`, `string.ascii_letters` and `_` are all strings. In this line, you are creating a list of strings:

```
>>> [string.digits, string.ascii_letters, "_"]
['0123456789', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '_']
```

When you later check if some character like `x` is in this list, of course it isn't, because the list doesn't contain a string `"x"`. Notably, `"_"` *is* a single character, so if the user enters a username like `____` I bet that would be accepted.

What you need to do is concatenate these all into one string:

```
allowed_chars = string.digits + string.ascii_letters + "_"
```

When you do `some_char in allowed_chars`, Python will automatically treat the string `allowed_chars` as a list of characters and the logic will work.

---

Now time for some things you didn't ask about, but I'll still lecture you on them :)

Don't name the string `filter`, this is already a function called that and you are making things confusing by replacing it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter

Incidentally, `filter()` is something you could use here to remove all allowed characters from the username, and see if anything is left, without using a for loop at all. I will leave that as an exercise to you.

Usually, if there's been an error, you should issue an exception. You can use `raise Exception("Unsupported character")` or `assert`. Read the docs about these, they will help you understand error handling.

You have a variable called `random_var` but it's actually not random at all, but stores each character of the username in order. Don't give things names that lie about what they do, it makes code extra confusing and hard to debug.

You don't need to use a while loop here. A while loop is useful when it's unpredictable how many times you're gonna go through the loop, because you are planning to evaluate the termination condition dynamically. In this case, you know exactly how many times you will loop, it's `len(username)`. In fact, you don't even need to count them, you can just tell Python to go through each letter:

```
for c in username:
    assert c in allowed_chars, "Character not supported in username: " + c
```

There, isn't that much cleaner? And as an exercise, I recommend you check out the [`any()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#any), which can allow you to do this in a very elegant way without any loops.

Lastly, don't use `input`, it sucks. It's very low level and IMO only useful as a building block for a UI framework. Use something like https://github.com/tmbo/questionary (you're welcome).

Oh and, there's no point actually checking each letter, because some will be repeats. If the first `e` in `nebuchadnezzar` is allowed, so will the second `e`. You should do `set(username)` to get the list of *unique* characters, and validate only those. Performance wise, it's kind of insignificant, but it's good to practice writing logical algorithms.

Comment: thanks for the useful tips. It’ll help me in my journey to become a coder, im still a beginner so im pretty bad at it

Comment: No problem - it's stuff I wish someone just told me when I was starting to learn Python. A lot of it took me years to figure out, and I wasted so much effort in the meanwhile as I was doing things the hard way. I highly recommend reading the official Python docs for everything you use, you'll learn to understand Python better than most people on this site. Also, don't neglect to search Github for Python packages that could be useful for your task, and read their documentation as well (if well written, if not, don't bother).